# Java Enhanced For-Loop: Referenced Collection Not Changed

Tags: java

Something strange is going on, suppose I have this code with 'Attachment' objects, and I want to set all the objects to NULL.

```
List<Attachment> attachments = getAttachments();

for (Attachment attachment: attachments)
{
   attachment = null;
}
```

The immediate object attachment is successfully set to NULL. But the backing collection is untouched. It still has the old data. I thought we could always rely on references in Java?

Comment: Nothing strange is going on.  Setting the value of a local variable doesn't affect other variables that happen to refer to the same object.

Comment: From the documentation on the [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html); it *is not usable for loops where you need to replace elements in a list or array as you traverse it.*

Comment: @azurefrog Well it affect other variables but in this particular case it won't as `foreach` is used.

Comment: But other for-loops are usable? It's only the special case of the enhanced for-each loop?

Comment: It cannot affect another *variable*.  If you run a method (e.g. `attachment.foo()`), then you will affect the *object* being referred to by another variable, which is not the same thing.

Comment: In Java you only have references and primitives, you don't have references to references. `attachment` is a reference which is a copy of the reference in the List.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on references in Java, if you understand them correctly.  You have a reference variable `attachment`, but it is one of 2 references referring to the object you want to set to `null`.

```
attachments -> { Attachment, Attachment, Attachment }
                     |           |           |
                     v           v           v
  attachment -->  (object)    (object)    (object)
```

When you assign `null` to `attachment`, the list reference isn't changed.

```
attachments -> { Attachment, Attachment, Attachment }
                     |           |           |
                     v           v           v
  attachment      (object)    (object)    (object)
      |
      v
    (null)
```

An enhanced for loop won't let you change the list contents this way.

You can use a traditional for loop, and call `set`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size; i++)
{
    attachments.set(i, null);
}
```

BTW, it's unclear why you want to set all elements to `null`.  This leaves *n* copies of `null` in the list.  An alternative is to remove all references to the list with `attachments.clear()`, which will leave no references at all in the list, not even `null`, in case that's what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** modify the contents of a `Collection` when traversing it in an enhanced for loop.

The `attachment` object that you get on every iteration is like a copy (it's actually just another reference to that object) of the object in the collection, so basically you are assigning null to that 'temporary' object, not to the actual element inside the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment of null to your attachment variable can not alter the collection because attachment is a reference to an Attachment object, not the collection itself.

Your attachments collection contains references to Attachment objects. Each iteration of the loop, Java assigns the next object reference in the collection to your attachment variable. If you subsequently change your attachment variable, that can not alter the collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier in the header of the enhanced `for` statement declares a *local variable*, as stated in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). In your case, `attachment` is a local variable. When you set it to `null`, it won't impact the object it is pointing to.